# What is AhcWSComponents in Lagom framework?

Tags: scala, reactive-programming, cqrs, lagom

It shows Object creation impossible, since member wsClient:WSClient is not defined,Whats is used for

```
class ShoppingCartLoader extends LagomApplicationLoader{
      override def load(context: LagomApplicationContext): LagomApplication = {

    //Commenting AhcWSComponents is giving error here
        new ShoppingCartApplication(context) {
          override def serviceLocator: ServiceLocator = NoServiceLocator
        }
      }

    }

 abstract class ShoppingCartApplication(context: LagomApplicationContext)
      extends LagomApplication(context)
        /*with AhcWSComponents*/{

      override lazy val lagomServer = serverFor[ShoppingCartService](wire[ShoppingCartImpl])

    }
```

Going inside AhcWSComponents, it has:

```
lazy val wsClient: WSClient = {
    implicit val mat    = materializer
    implicit val ec     = executionContext
    val asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClientProvider(environment, configuration, applicationLifecycle).get
    new AhcWSClientProvider(asyncHttpClient).get
  }
```

If it is needed, then why is it not included in `LagomApplication` itself

Answer (score 1):

A `LagomApplication` is required to have a `wsClient` in order to have a uniform interface for making HTTP requests to external services.  The AsyncHttpClient-based implementation (pulled in through `AhcWSComponents`) is included, but it's fully OK to use a different implementation as long as the contracts are met.  Thus the decision to use the included implementation is made explicit by mixing in the `AhcWSComponents`.

One benefit of this requirement arises when it comes time to write tests for functionality which depend on making requests to external services: you can have an implementation which mocks the external services and use that implementation in all your tests, rather than having to set up the same mocks in a multitude of suites.  However, to take advantage of that, you don't want to mix in the implementation at the level of the abstract class:

```
class ShoppingCartLoader extends LagomApplicationLoader {
  override def load(context: LagomApplicationContext): LagomApplication = {
    // as above until
    new ShoppingCartApplication(context) with AhcWSComponents {
      override def serviceLocator: ServiceLocator = NoServiceLocator
    }
  }
}

// now you don't need `with AhcWSComponents` on the abstract class
```

Then in your tests, when you need a `LagomApplication`:

```
new ShoppingCartApplication(context) {
  override def wsClient: WSClient = ??? // mock implementation here
}
```